# how to get screenshots for tablet

Tags: applications, google-play-store, screenshots

My game is on the google play store (beta testing). How do I get screen shots of the app running on a 7 inch and 11 inch tablet so I can put images of how the game looks in the store listing?

Comment: if anyone with a 11 inch tablet can help - please share an email id as a comment and delete it later

Comment: I do have both a 7- and 10-incher, though I'd wait a bit for other answers to possibly pop up before sharing my mail.

Comment: @EelaKapilla You need to take screenshots or a video of the game in play. Again why not use the conventional method of taking screenshots using the physical buttons...

Comment: @user145490 I think the problem is not that he can't do the screenshot, but rather he doesn't have tablets (different layout, can't be substituted with phones) to do screenshots on.

Comment: To OP: is Android AVD (comes with SDK) viable for you? Or more efficient emulators like Genymotion? Can they run your game at acceptable performance?

Comment: @andy-yan game still in dev and only on usual phones. did not think the emulator screen shot will be accepted. anyway i though it was a easy request. will try with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing Screenshot

1. Install the required ADB drivers on your PC.
2. Connect your device with PC using wired or wireless ADB connection.
3. Open Terminal in Linux or Command Prompt and enter the following command.

adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.png

4. Now the captured screenshot will be placed on your internal sdcard. To copy the screenshot to your pc enter the command.

adb pull /sdcard/screencap.png

5. Now the captured screenshot will be placed on your PC

Comment: I think the problem is not that he can't do the screenshot, but rather he doesn't have tablets (different layout, can't be substituted with phones) to do screenshots on.

Comment: yes i do not have the device